Error `Can't determine project language from files.` when using Azure Functions in VSCode
In this tutorial, when I run the function in step Create a function app to enrich your search index, I get error
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--dotnet-isolated, --dotnet, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]

As per this link, it seems I need to add variable FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME in local settings file but the the zip file didn't come with the settings file.
How do I resolve the error?
There is a settings.json file in .vscode folder, which specifies that the project language is python.
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}


the error is throwing becuse you have not added local.settings.json file in the project when running locally you need to add local settings.json file. I was also getting same error. After adding the creating file and adding these values it worked fine. image1 image2. I am just executing the function file.

Those are degault values in local.settings.json file. if any other environment variables are required you can add in it.

As I mentioned in comment, I was also getting the same error when i downloaded the zip file from the link.

To resolve this error create a file  local.settings.json an set its value to below given data. These value are the required values for running python function locally.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  }
}

OUTPUT:
Just executing the downloaded zip file. That is why in getting invalid body in response here.


